# Cannot set Android download manager downloading files location and cannot get real file name

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm developing an application and using built in Android download manager class. I want to download files into a folder called "myApp" (folder already exists). This is what I tried. I also tried different methods to set download location.But they are not working. Please help to fix this issue.

```
  DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) this.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        boolean isDownloading = false;
        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
        query.setFilterByStatus(
                DownloadManager.STATUS_PAUSED|
                        DownloadManager.STATUS_PENDING|
                        DownloadManager.STATUS_RUNNING|
                        DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL
        );
        Cursor cur = mgr.query(query);
        int col = cur.getColumnIndex(
                DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME);
        for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()) {
            isDownloading = isDownloading || ("local file path" == cur.getString(col));
        }
        cur.close();

        if (!isDownloading) {
            Uri source = Uri.parse(myWebsites[j]);

            Uri dst_uri = Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/Signagee");

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);

            request.setDestinationUri(dst_uri);
            request.setNotificationVisibility(
                    DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED
            );
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

            long id = mgr.enqueue(request);
        }
```

Comment: do not use hardcoded paths like `/mnt/sdcard/`. Use `Environment` class

Comment: Can you help to get the file name.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
```

All the downloads will get downloaded in Downloads folder. You can choose any other destination from the Environment class.

To get the file name check this

```
String filePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
        filename = filePath.substring( filePath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, filePath.length() );
```

Use this `filename` in above line

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. But still I cannot get real file name of the downloading file. @Sallu. please help

Comment: @Sallu- Yes I also found this answer and tried like this

 for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()) {
                isDownloading = isDownloading || ("local file path" == cur.getString(col));
                title = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TITLE));
                String filePath = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
                filename = filePath.substring( filePath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, filePath.length() );

            }
But I cannot use  'filename' outside the loop

Comment: done. but can you please help me with the title. I added a comment above

Comment: @venura what error are you getting in title? can you specify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141956/discussion-between-venura-and-sallu).

Comment: If I add above title code. I have to use it inside for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext()) {  in my code.
Then I cannot use it in request .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir
Because varialbe it outside from the loop